# Excel file Processing using Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

There are 10 excel files in on premise machine and each excel file contains different number of sheets and the sheets will vary dynamically(mostly increasing the sheets).For example Excel-1 contains two different sheets in the initial days and the later third sheet included in the file. Need to process accordingly and pick only the few required column from each sheet .Once after picking the columns need to join those 10 excel files and get the columns from each excel and load into final Sql table(Assume Sql table contains 100 columns and columns are coming from all the excels).

Best approach to design the Azure data factory pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Of course this can be done with the mapping dataflow. You can take those excel files as seperate sources, join them, if you need to select certain columns, use select transformation etc. In source you need to specify where the file will be coming from. You can add new source by adding a new dataset, and you can add many sources as you like and include them in joins. All join logic is based on merge logic from spark.

In the linked service to .xls or .xlsx files you can specify worksheet mode(name or index) and sheet name. you can also parameterize these values.

[image: Excel Linked Service]

[image: Multiple joins]

Comment: this works only for one excel file what if we have multiple excel files and choose only selected columns among those

Comment: Hello for every file to be joined, you need to create another join activity. Like in this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbDTBAyYte8

I have also updated my answer with new photo from video. please confirm if my answer helped you :)

Comment: Additionally, one more option you have is to use merge in copy activity, in that case you can wildcard the path and put all your excel files there, and if all the columns are the same for each files (the behaviour is different if columns are not), they should be merged regardless of how many they are. Maybe its better practice to merge files like that, and do your joins with specific requirements in the dataflow later in an adjacent connected dataflow activity.